# Error: Table or view does not exist while creating a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting an error on executing the following pl/SQL (SQL developer) in DB2 (just a name):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REF_COPY_DB(
v_QUERY_SCHEMA in VARCHAR2
)
AS
    select_columns  VARCHAR(10000);

BEGIN
  insert into v_QUERY_SCHEMA.DATA_COPY_STATUS (DO_NAME, TABLE_NAME, STATUS) VALUES ('test','test','test');
END;
/
```

**Error:**

```
Procedure REF_COPY_DB compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
8/3       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/30      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Errors: check compiler log
```

I am not sure why the error table or view does not exist is coming because I am not calling the procedure. I am just creating the procedure.
I am planning to call the procedure with argument `DB1` and DB1 does already have a table with the name DATA_COPY_STATUS. Not sure what could be the reason for this.

Could this be a permission issue? If so what permissions may be required and how can I grant permissions here? Here I am trying to run a procedure in Schema2 which inserts data into a table in Schema1
**Things I tried:**
Execute grant insert, update, delete on DATA_COPY_STATUS to DB1 <-- ran this on DB2
I am able to query select * from DB2.DATA_COPY_STATUS on DB1

Answer (score 2):

You can't supply identifiers (including schema, table and column names) at runtime with static SQL. When you compile your procedure it is looking for a table in a schema called literally "V_QUERY_SCHEMA", which doesn't exist.

If you need to supply the schema at runtime you would need to use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REF_COPY_DB(
v_QUERY_SCHEMA in VARCHAR2
)
AS
  l_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_stmt := 'insert into "'
    || dbms_assert.schema_name(v_QUERY_SCHEMA)
    || '".DATA_COPY_STATUS (DO_NAME, TABLE_NAME, STATUS)'
    || ' VALUES (:c1, :c2, :c3)';
  -- to debug
  dbms_output.put_line(l_stmt);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_stmt USING 'test','test','test';
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bjfCvRDp)

I've used bind variables (`:c1` etc, and `USING`) for the parts that can be variable. The schema name can't be so that has to be embedded in the statement. I've used [`DBMS_ASSERT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_ASSERT.html#GUID-84022DB8-B6AB-420D-B031-74DEBF1AAAA9) to mitigate against the threat of SQL injection; and that is quoted as the docs recommend. Note that the value passed in has to be the schema name as it appears in the data dictionary, including case - so usually (but not necessarily) uppercase.

If the `select_columns` you have defined is going to be used in the statement then that will also need to be embedded; depending on how that is set/populated you need to be careful about injection there too. I'd guess you'll be querying the data dictionary for that eventually though.

Also bear in mind that by default the owner of the procedure has to have privileges on the table granted directly, not through a role. With that setup the *caller* of the procedure doesn't need to be able to see the table. If you want to make sure the caller has to have the privileges (directly or through a role) then you can look at [invoker's rights](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/invokers_rights_clause.html).